# Filtering with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, filtering

I apologize in advance if this explanation is not 100% clear.

I am trying to list users in order based on their ratings (and then ordered by their userids).  I am actually trying to paginate the results because there could potentially be a large number of results.

I have two tables:

- Table A : with column "userid"
- Table B : with columns "rating" and "userid" and "groupid"

There are other columns but these are the relevant ones here.

Every user can submit a rating of a group using the following values: -1, 0, or 1 which is recorded in "rating".  Each group's net rating is evaluated by getting the net summation of "status" ratings that correspond to a given group.

I have this basic query:

```
SELECT groupid, userid, SUM(rating) 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.userid = B.userid 
GROUP BY A.userid 
ORDER BY SUM(rating) DESC, A.userid ASC
```

However, I'd like to paginate so I need to be able to choose results based on the last userid that was previously displayed.

Normally, it would be easy to filter results based on any results that has userid greater than the last userid displayed.  However, since I am ordering the results based on SUM(rating), there is really no sequential ordering system.

Is there a good way to filter my results for pagination purposes even though my userid's in the results are not ordered sequentially?

Comment: whats you host ide? or just pure SQL?

Comment: The only thing i can think may work here, is to create another  table which is populated with the rating order of your user IDs. You will have tyo keep this up date date whener ratings are changed. So when you run your overall query,use this table to join with your Table B and use this order field in the order by clause

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using limit with an offset?

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  The LIMIT w/ offset works fine.  The problem is getting the "next" user which would be based on the last userid that was displayed.

Comment: Before I've parsed the first row in the url with something like ?p=29 then just offset the limit adding 1 to that row number

Comment: yup, tried that...problem is that the results are ordered based on the sum(rating) and not by userids.  Because the results are not sequentially listed by userids I can't specify something like ?p=29.

Comment: I've done i little example with one of my own db tables and limit works on row number for me not ids. if i put 'limit 30,20' at the end of a statement with a sum column it goes straight to the 30th row and displays 20results. Forgot return was post!

Comment: That's the query I'm starting with...but I need to add limit offset (LIMIT 0, 10) for example - this isn't a problem.  However, I also need to have a statement that will choose only results after the "last" userid used.  Problem is that a simple comparison on the userid won't work since the results are not sequential based on the userids.

Comment: SELECT groupid, userid, SUM(rating) 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.userid = B.userid 
GROUP BY A.userid WHERE A.userID > $last 
ORDER BY SUM(rating) DESC, A.userid ASC  --- this won't work because userids are not sequential